# show/hide form input fields based on menu selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to get certain input hidden field data to load based on menu selections.  But I can't get it to work with this code below.  Can you help me find out where I'm going wrong?  I'd like to try and get this code working.

I currently have this javascript in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle() {
        //alert(thing.options[thing.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
        var w = document.getElementById("pt").selectedIndex;
        var selected_text = document.getElementById("pt").options[w].text;
        if (selected_text == "Home") {
            //alert(selected_text)
            document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="sfrType[]" value="RES-Single Family"><input type="hidden" name="sfrType[]" value="RES-Farm-Ranch">'
        } else if (selected_text == "Lot") {
            // alert(selected_text)
            document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" id="amin_acres" name="amin_acres" value="0.001">'
        } else if (selected_text == "Acreage") {
            //alert(selected_text)
            document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="amin_acres" value="2">'
        } else {
            document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's the field form menu html:

```
<select name="pt" id="pt" onChange="toggle()" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="sfr" selected="selected">Home</option>
    <option value="ld">Lot</option>
    <option value="ld">Acreage</option>
    <option value="com">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

So if `Acreage` is selected, then input hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="amin_acres" value="2">` will load.  It used to work and then it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure to add the div

`<div id="hiddenbox"></div>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle() {
//alert(thing.options[thing.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
var w = document.getElementById("pt").selectedIndex;
var selected_text = document.getElementById("pt").options[w].text;
 if (selected_text == "Home") {
    //alert(selected_text)
  document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '<input  name="sfrType[]" value="RES-Single Family"><input type="hidden" name="sfrType[]" value="RES-Farm-Ranch">'
  }   
 else if  (selected_text == "Lot") {
   // alert(selected_text)
  document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '<input  id="amin_acres" name="amin_acres" value="0.001">'
  }   
 else if (selected_text == "Acreage") {
    //alert(selected_text)
  document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML = '<input  name="amin_acres" value="2">'
 } else {
  document.getElementById("hiddenbox").innerHTML ='';
 }
}

 </script>
```

Comment: Where does the hiddenbox div go?  Also the form fields need to be hidden but processed when the form submits based on the menu selection.  These input fields are to only appear in the background html and not shown to the user submitting the form.

Comment: I had to try the code in a test project, and work perfectly, must be something else wrong, maybe with your db

Comment: Yeah, I found there was 2 toggles in the header code.  All is working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are lose the #hiddenbox element.

```
<div id="hiddenbox"></div>
<select name="pt" id="pt" onChange="toggle()" size="5" multiple="multiple"> 
  <option value="sfr" selected="selected">Home</option> 
  <option value="ld">Lot</option> 
  <option value="ld">Acreage</option> 
  <option value="com">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You put the type as hidden for your input tags. Therefore, the input types will not show. Also, it is good practice to wrap your input tags with a form tag as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp). I hope this helps!

Comment: it already is wrapped in a form.  This is just a section of the form.  Also the hidden fields need to be hidden, but still get acknowledged for the form submission.  Just not who up visually in the form.